# String^ to LPCTSTR in VC++2010 (Windows form application)

Tags: string, c++-cli, file-copying

How to convert System::string^ in to LPCTSTR ?
As my requirement is to clone a file using function **CopyFile**, it works fine if i give Fix name (OldFile.jpg and LatestFile.jpg) to its parameters (**below Code: Works Fine**)

```
LPCTSTR in_f,out_f;

in_f    =   _T("d:\\Old.jpg");
out_f   =   _T("d:\\Latest.jpg");

CopyFile(in_f,out_f,false);
```

above code clone the Old.jpeg in to a Latest.jpg but when i trying to give name (Latest.jpg) which is coming out from some String it won't create file (**below Code: NOT Working**)

```
  String^   Name    =   "Latest";

//------Capture Current Date & Time
    DateTime datetime = DateTime::Now;

//-------Convert Date Timt in to String
    Name    =   Name + String::Format("{0}",datetime); 
    Name    =   Name->Replace('/','-');
    Name    =   Name->Replace(':','-');
    Name    =   Name    +   ".jpg";    

    LPCTSTR in_f,out_f;

    in_f    =   _T("d:\\Old.jpg");
    out_f   =   (LPCTSTR)Name; //Trying to Assign Current Latest file Name With date Time here

    CopyFile(in_f,out_f,false);
```

The Problem is CopyFile Took LPCTSTR type as an argument , where as i am giving a type System::string^, So suggest me how to convert this System::string^ in to LPCTSTR so that i can add the current date time with in the name of my file.
**I am Using VC++2010 and Windows form Application**

Comment: How about [converting the string to an array of characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp), and then getting a pointer to the characters from the array?

Comment: Use Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi or StringToHGlobalUnicode, depending on whether you build with UNICODE in effect.  Do strive to get rid of tchar, it is hopelessly obsolete, use CopyFileW so you can rely on LPCWSTR.  And of course consider to use File::Copy() instead so none of this is necessary.

Comment: In .NET use [System.IO.File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: This Solution Works, only Thing is use "StringToHGlobalUni"  instead of "StringToHGlobalUnicode" and also Close it by "Marshal::FreeHGlobal"

Answer (score 1):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

I'm not sure I agree with Hans's comment that TCHAR is obsolete, but doing an explicit conversion to a wide string and calling `CopyFileW` is a good option.

Also, one could go the other direction, and convert from unmanaged to managed strings, and use the .Net method to copy files, [`File::Copy(String^, String^, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

To convert to a `LPCTSTR`, I would use marshal_as. Because it's implemented with templates, the compiler will resolve your `LPCTSTR` to call either the `LPCSTR` or `LPCWSTR` version, as appropriate.

Microsoft doesn't have dedicated documentation pages for each templated version of `marshal_as`, but the [Overview of Marshaling in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp) page is a good place to start.

My test program:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    String^ managedStr = "I came from managed land!\r\n";

    // This controls the lifetime of the LPCTSTR that marshal_as returns. 
    // When this goes out of scope, the LPCTSTR will no longer be valid, 
    // so be aware of its lifetime.
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;

    LPCTSTR unmanagedStr = context.marshal_as<LPCTSTR>(managedStr);

    OutputDebugString(unmanagedStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
I came from managed land!
```

Comment: Are you really recommending MFC and LPCTSTR in 2017? :-\

Comment: In comparison to C++/CLI WinForms, which is oddly easy to select in Visual Studio and may have been selected by someone that didn't realize the difference? Absolutely. (Of course, I'd recommend C# over either of them, but there may reasons why C++ is required.)

Comment: I don't know much about current C++ GUI frameworks, but I said that because I remember how much of a PITA MFC was back in the day. I'm pretty sure there must be something better now. BTW there's no C++/CLI WinForms app project template anymore in VS, yay! :-) But I'm genuinely interested in why you think `TCHAR` is *not* obsolete... The last time I used ANSI functions was for win 98...

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a \0 character at the end of the Name string, since CopyFile() expects zero-terminated strings.

**EDIT:** *As LucasTrzesniewski has pointed out, pinning a .NET string automatically yields a zero-terminated character array. This is documented in the C# specification. See the comments below for more information.*

Moreover, you have to "pin" the string in memory, so the garbage collector won't move it around. Then you can create a pointer to the first character of the string. C++/CLI provides some utility types and functions to do this. Here's an example:

```
pin_ptr<const WCHAR> psName = PtrToStringChars (Name)
```

PtrToStringChars() is an inline function declared in vcclr.h. psName should be assignable to a LPCTSTR parameter - if not, use a cast. Note that PtrToStringChars() doesn't work if the input string is a nullptr. You need to test explicitly for this case. (However, in your case, Name is certainly not a nullptr).

The String remains pinned until the variable psName gets out of scope. This happens after leaving the { ... } block in which it's declared, e.g. after leaving the current function. No explicit unpinning is needed.

Comment: No need to add a null terminator, as .NET strings already have one. Pinning is the most lightweight solution as it doesn't require string copying. The string will be assignable to LPCWSTR, or LPCTSTR only if UNICODE is set, which should be the case unless you're developing for Windows 98... It's better to use LPCWSTR explicitly though.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the info about zero termination - actually, I didn't know that. Is this officially documented in the .NET standard?

Comment: I was unable to find a reference to this in ECMA-335, which surprised me TBH. But it's definitely implemented in .NET: The C# spec explicitly [states the following](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/unsafe-code.md#the-fixed-statement): *A `char*` value produced by fixing a `string` instance always points to a null-terminated string. [...] The automatic null-termination of strings is particularly convenient when calling external APIs that expect "C-style" strings.* (a C# `char` is the same as `wchar_t` in C++)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks once again for this interesting information. The C# spec is obviously quite clear about zero termination, so I think it's safe to assume that explicit termination is not necessary.

Comment: The title explicitly says Visual 2010: Why use PtrToStringChars() or StringToHGlobalAnsi when you can use `marshal_as<LPCTSTR>` which does all of the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: @Medinoc According to Microsoft Help, PtrToStringChars() is available on VS 2010: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/585whdf9(v=vs.100).aspx It is the most efficient way to pass a string pointer from managed to unmanaged, because it doesn't require string copying. PtrToStringChars() is a trivial inline function: It casts the String^ to a byte array, then adds the magic offset `System::Runtime::CompilerServices::RuntimeHelpers::OffsetToStringData`, and casts the resulting pointer back to a `const WCHAR*`. It hardly can get any faster.

Comment: @SBS Sure it's fast, but it requires you to explicitly use CopyFileW instead of CopyFile, or be That Guy who mixes and doesn't match.

Comment: @Medinoc: There's an inline function called `CopyFile` in `WinBase.h` that evaluates to a `CopyFileW()` call in a UNICODE environment. So what's the problem you are pointing to?

Comment: The point of the second half of my last comment is that *if you code no longer works once you flip the UNICODE switch in the project options, you're a bad Windows programmer*.

Comment: @Medinoc As long as you don't need to target Windows 98, the UNICODE switch will be flipped already anyway. Frankly, the last time I've used the Windows ANSI functions was about 15 years ago. It was always a pain to support that brain-dead operating system, and I'm not going to support it anymore. Time to wave it goodbye already. Does this make me a "bad Windows programmer?!" I'm sorry if you still have to support Win98... real sorry...

Comment: @SBS In your rage to bury "obsolete" backward compatibility, you hurt forward compatibility as well. Congratulations.

Comment: @Medinoc This discussion is getting pointless... Nevermind, using PtrToStringChars() is what Microsoft officially recommends for accessing "characters of a String object for high-performance calls to unmanaged functions that take wchar_t* strings", and I stated exactly this information in my answer. Nothing more, nothing less, hoping to help. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/585whdf9.aspx

Comment: @Medinoc I really hope we won't get back to ASCII and the code page madness in the future. And that `_T` stuff makes code ugly as hell. Just let Win98 die already.

Answer (score -2):

You need to marshaling it to "const char *" and make a static_cast to LPCTSTR.

Take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

Comment: Blindly `static_cast`ing to LPCTSTR is a good way to summon nasal demons, but NOT a good way to program for Win32.