# incompatible with parameter of type "LPCTSTR"

Tags: c++-cli

So i got this error:

> argument of type `System::String ^` is incompatible with parameter of
>   type `LPCTSTR`

When i try to use this code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ currentDesktop = System::Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Desktop\\Test";
    CreateDirectory (currentDesktop, NULL);
    String^ value = (this->listBox1)->Text;
    MessageBox::Show ("File has been created successfully. You've choosen: " + value, "Success", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}
};
```

So i don't know exactly where is the problem, So help me please.

Comment: That's not C++ but (I think) C++/CLI. That said, please first take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also make sure you have done some research on the error message.

Comment: this is not C++, it's C++/CLI. As a side note, C++/CLI is deprecated so, unless you work with some legacy code you might consider changing the language.

Comment: you can convert string to const char * with c_str and thn to wide char by CA2W

Comment: i'm using Visual Studio 2017 so, it creates the program's codes for you,

Comment: Since you have a .NET `System::String^`, you probably would want to call the .NET directory management function `Directory::Create()` instead of the native WinAPI function `CreateDirectory`.  But if you really want to call the OS directly, there's `PtrToStringChars`, which is nicely wrapped by `marshal_as`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String^ to LPCTSTR in VC++2010 (Windows form application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115050/string-to-lpctstr-in-vc2010-windows-form-application)

Comment: Do you guys know how to make Visual Studio 2017, using c++ instead of c++/cli

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, and thank you @Ben Voigt

This code working fine:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ currentDesktop = System::Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Desktop\\Test";
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    LPCTSTR desktop = context.marshal_as<LPCTSTR>(currentDesktop);
    CreateDirectory (desktop, NULL);
    String^ value = (this->listBox1)->Text;
    MessageBox::Show ("File has been created successfully. You've choosen: " + value, "Success", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}
};
```

Comment: There is no point in doing it this way, use [Directory::CreateDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2).